# Python: i would like to have an error message?

Tags: python, tkinter

i would like to show an error message once both entry have got the same input and if its possible not to print those values in the csv file. could you please help?

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.output()

    def output(self):
        self.playerA = Label(text='state player Name A:').pack()
        self.E1 = Entry(root, bd=5)
        self.E1.pack()

        self.playerB = Label(text='state player Name A:').pack()
        self.E2 = Entry(root, bd=5)
        self.E2.pack()


        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('ttest.csv', 'a') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.E1.get()])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root=Tk()
    root.title('insert new scores')
    root.geometry('200x200')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need? It looks like you know how to create widgets, and you know how to call functions when buttons are pressed. What part of the problem are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `EntryException` class, and `raise` it if the values in both entry fields are equal:

When both entries are different, a record is written in the csv file.
When they are different, an `EntryException` is raised, and nothing gets written in the file.

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv

class EntryException(BaseException):
    pass

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.output()

    def output(self):
        self.playerA = Label(text='state player Name A:').pack()
        self.E1 = Entry(root, bd=5)
        self.E1.pack()

        self.playerB = Label(text='state player Name A:').pack()
        self.E2 = Entry(root, bd=5)
        self.E2.pack()


        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def writeToFile(self):
        if self.E1.get() == self.E2.get():
            raise EntryException
        else:
            with open('ttest.csv', 'a') as f:
                w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                w.writerow([self.E1.get()])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root=Tk()
    root.title('insert new scores')
    root.geometry('200x200')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the message box for displaying the message/error if both numbers are equal.

```
from tkinter import messagebox

def writeToFile(self):
    if(self.E1.get()==self.E2.get()):
        messagebox.showinfo("Message", "Both Values are Equal")
    else:
        with open('test.csv', 'a') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.E1.get()])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a simple check in the writeToFile() function before writing...

```
    def writeToFile(self):
        #start new chunk
        from tkinter import messagebox 
        if self.E1.get() == self.E2.get():
            messagebox.showerror('Error Message', "Both Users have the name '{}'".format(self.E1.get()))
            return
        #end new chunk
        with open('ttest.csv', 'a') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.E1.get(), self.E2.get()])
            #                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The tkinter messagebox has a few simple dialog message options:
 `showerror()`, `showwarning()`, and `showinfo()`.  Play with them and choose the one that gives the look and feel you like. Also, I included writing the second user name into the CSV file if they are not the same, in case you overlooked that.